# Weird link being generated by Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this:

```
public class PagesModel
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public int PagesCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }
    public object HtmlAttributes { get; set; }
}

public static MvcHtmlString RenderPages(this HtmlHelper helper, PagesModel pages, bool isNextAndPrev = false)
{
    //some code
    var lastPageSpan = new TagBuilder("span");
    var firstValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(pages.RouteValues) { { "page", pages.PagesCount } };
    lastPageSpan.InnerHtml = helper.ActionLink(">>", pages.ActionName, pages.ControllerName, firstValueDictionary, pages.HtmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(lastPageSpan.ToString());
}
```

The link it generates looks like this: `<span><a href="/Forums/Thread?Count=2&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D">&gt;&gt;</a></span>`

Why? What am I doing wrong? When i put a breakpoint before setting `.innerHtml`, i see that my `firstValueDictionary` looks totally normal. What is going on?

**Update**: When i replace `RouteValueDictionary` parameter with freshly created anonymous type (`new {page = 0}`), then everything works fine. Why can't I use predefined `RouteValueDictionary`?

Comment: the `to stirng` is returning the erro which is thrown by the helper.Action

Comment: No. The `helper.ActionLink(">>", pages.ActionName, pages.ControllerName, firstValueDictionary, pages.HtmlAttributes)` is actually creating the wrong link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload of the ActionLink helper. Try like this:

```
lastPageSpan.InnerHtml = helper.ActionLink(
    ">>", 
    pages.ActionName, 
    pages.ControllerName, 
    firstValueDictionary, 
    new RouteValueDictionary(pages.HtmlAttributes) // <!-- HERE!
).ToHtmlString();
```

Here's the [`overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) you were using:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

And here's the [`correct overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) you need to use:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice the difference?